# How to calculate only in all cells have value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The formula that ONLY displays a sum when ALL the cells it's calculating contain values, otherwise it remains blank.

For example, if the formula calculates over 3 cells but only 2 of those cells have values then no sum is shown in the calulation cell-  it remains a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
{=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1:C1)),SUM(A1:C1),"")}
```

It is an array formula and must be entered using by pressing `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `Enter` at the same time.  If you get it right you will see the `{` and `}` brackets around the formula automatically.

### How it works

`ISNUMBER` ensures the cells only have numbers stored inside.

`AND` ensure that all the cells have numbers

`IF` should be self explanatory.

### Other information

You can easily check to see if a range of cells have contents by this formula,

```
{=IF(AND(--(LEN(A1:C1))),TRUE,FALSE)}
```

`Len` returns the number of characters in the cell.

`--` converts the result to a Boolean value (TRUE or FALSE)